# vagrant halt hanging while trying to detect guest OS

Tags: centos, vagrant

I'm trying to halt a vagrant vm using 'vagrant halt' and it seems to be hanging up on detecting the guest OS. (vagrant 1.5.1, centos 6.5 vm). Is this a bug in vagrant or something wrong with our base box?

Debug log for vagrant halt:

`DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: grep 'Fedora release [12][67890]' /etc/redhat-release (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
...snip
DEBUG guest: Trying: ubuntu
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: cat /etc/issue | grep 'Ubuntu' (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
...
DEBUG guest: Trying: suse
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: cat /etc/SuSE-release (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
...
DEBUG guest: Trying: pld
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: cat /etc/pld-release (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
...
DEBUG guest: Trying: arch`

At the point when vagrant is trying to detect the os I start seeing segfaults in /var/log/messages

`May  1 11:52:19 localhost kernel: bash[21880]: segfault at 7ffff4db3e64 ip 0000000000424add sp 00007ffff4db3e30 error 6 in bash[400000+d4000]
May  1 11:52:20 localhost abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2014-05-01-11:52:19-21880' creation detected
May  1 11:52:20 localhost abrt[21881]: Saved core dump of pid 21880 (/bin/bash) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2014-05-01-11:52:19-21880 (65454080 bytes)
May  1 11:52:20 localhost kernel: bash[21883]: segfault at 7ffff4db3e64 ip 0000000000424add sp 00007ffff4db3e30 error 6 in bash[400000+d4000]
May  1 11:52:20 localhost abrt[21884]: Not saving repeating crash in '/bin/bash'
May  1 11:52:20 localhost kernel: bash[7759]: segfault at 7ffff4db3f98 ip 0000000000422105 sp 00007ffff4db3fa0 error 6 in bash[400000+d4000]
May  1 11:52:20 localhost abrt[21886]: Not saving repeating crash in '/bin/bash'
May  1 11:52:24 localhost kernel: Bridge firewalling registered
May  1 11:53:51 localhost kernel: bash[3725]: segfault at 7fffd5939da4 ip 0000000000424add sp 00007fffd5939d70 error 6 in bash[400000+d4000]
May  1 11:53:51 localhost abrt[3726]: Saved core dump of pid 3725 (/bin/bash) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2014-05-01-11:53:51-3725 (65454080 bytes)
May  1 11:53:51 localhost abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2014-05-01-11:53:51-3725' creation detected
May  1 11:53:51 localhost kernel: bash[3727]: segfault at 7fffd5939da4 ip 0000000000424add sp 00007fffd5939d70 error 6 in bash[400000+d4000]
May  1 11:53:51 localhost abrt[3728]: Not saving repeating crash in '/bin/bash'
May  1 11:53:51 localhost kernel: bash[21887]: segfault at 7fffd5939fb4 ip 0000000000424add sp 00007fffd5939f80 error 6 in bash[400000+d4000]
May  1 11:53:51 localhost abrt[3729]: Not saving repeating crash in '/bin/bash'
May  1 11:54:15 localhost abrtd: Sending an email...
May  1 11:54:15 localhost abrtd: Email was sent to: root@localhost
May  1 11:54:15 localhost abrtd: New problem directory /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2014-05-01-11:52:19-21880, processing`

http://pastebin.com/bUAneJY5

I tried to set config.vm.guest = :linux (i don't know if there is an option for centos specifically) and it won't even boot up giving another error:

`Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'change_host_name'
on the detect guest OS 'linux', but the guest doesn't
support that capability. This capability is required for your
configuration of Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to
avoid this capability or fix the issue by creating the capability.`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is being fixed by 1.6 release:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3602